# How do I save the values of the columns in separate variables in python?

Tags: python

I have a table with two columns. What code should I write so that each variable stores all the values in each columns.

Comment: Do you mean a database table? Are you familiar with Python dictionaries? Are you looking for a tutorial?

Comment: We need more information to give you an appropriate answer. Maybe the use of the csv module and append function helps you